# fcgi php.ini override

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, centos

I'm using `cPanel` on `centos5` 64bit installed.

PHP handler is : `fcgi`

`cat /usr/local/apache/conf/php.conf` output is :

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
MaxRequestsPerProcess 500
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php5
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php4
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php3
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php2
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .phtml
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5 .php4 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml
```

Apache/2.2.22, PHP 5.2.17

How can i use custom php.ini for a specific account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple shell wrapper like this :

```
# cat > /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5-custom
#!/bin/sh

exec /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 --php-ini /path/to/php-custom.ini "$@"
(EOF)
# chmod +x /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5-custom
```

Then in a specific context, like a virtualhost, override the fcgiwrapper for the type you need :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5-custom .php
</VirtualHost>
```